# NavigationComponents Transparent toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

Is there a way to set transparent toolbar just for the main activity that holds all my fragments ?

I need to show the toolbar in other fragments but in the main host activity I want it transparent with buttons instead of colored

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        setupActionBar(navController)
    }

    private fun setupActionBar(navController: NavController) {
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigateUp()
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
        menu!!.findItem(R.id.eventFragment)?.isVisible = false
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
}
```

From here I wonder If I can make my toolbar transparent in this activity only

I have searched but has not found nothing about Navigation Components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle Action Bars/Toolbars is to use Theme.NoActionBar and then create one on you own and set the background color to transparent.

This cloud look like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.settings.SettingsActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/settingsToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/settings_navigation" />
```

Comment: Do I need to provide to each fragment the AppBarLayout or just to the host activity?

Comment: As you can see in my example, this is not a normal fragment, this is the NavHostFragment which provides every fragment in this navigation component. For more details: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/organize-your-settings 
If you don't want to use navigation components, then yes you just have to do that in your activity.

So short answer: it is enough if you define it in your activity.

Answer (score 1):

By using the addOnDestinationChangedListener method of the NavController on your MainActivity, you can set the toolbar color for every fragment that depends on your NavHostFragment. You could have something similar to this:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination: NavDestination, _ ->
        when (destination.id) {
            R.id.feedFragment -> { setToolbarColor(R.color.white) }
            R.id.infoFragment -> { setToolbarColor(R.color.transparent)}}}


private fun setToolbarColor(colorId : Int){
    supportActionBar!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorId)))
}
```

I'd like to find a cleaner way to do it but it was the first approach that worked for me after trying different ones.

Comment: If you feel the code in this answer solves the problem you should [edit] it and explain how and why it does so. Especially since another contribution has already been marked as the Answer to the question. Code without explanation is not useful for future users of the site.

Answer (score 1):

[image]**Transparent toolbar**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@drawable/background_toolbar_translucent">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_menu"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtToolbarDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:text="August 8"
                android:fontFamily="@font/questrial_regular"
                android:drawableTint="@color/colorBlack"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ccp_ic_arrow_drop_down"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        />

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/notification_view_holder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/addCaseBtnHome"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_7sdp"
                       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6sdp"
                       android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_button_station"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

**use this drawable xml for background**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:startColor="@color/black_alpha_40"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: <color name="black_alpha_40">#66000000</color>